# Range of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

$\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are defined in terms of $e^{iz}$ if $z$ is a complex number . We know that $\sin$ and $\cos$ have range $[-1,1]$ in real system. How can one find the range of complex functions?

EDIT: Your comment suggests that both $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ have full complex plane as range. What is wrong in the following reasoning?

$\cos z = {(e^{iz} + e^{-iz})/2}$ , so $|\cos z| = |(e^{iz} + e^{-iz})|/2  $
 $\leqslant(1 + 1)/2 = 1$ as $|e^{iz}|=1$

Comment: How is $e^{iz}$ defined?

Comment: $e^z$ is $1+z+z^{2}/2! + ... $

Comment: By [Little Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), the range of any non-constant entire function is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.

Comment: Is there any general approach that uses something like there exists solution for any complex number $a = sin z$?

Comment: Since $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$, finding a $z$ for $\sin z = a$ is equivalent to find a $u$ for $u^2 - 2ia u - 1 = 0$ and then find a $z$ for $u = e^{iz}$. It is easy to see both steps are possible, so the range of $\sin z$ is the whole complex plane.

Comment: $\lvert e^{i(x+iy)} \rvert = \lvert e^{-y}e^{ix} \rvert = e^{-y} \ne 1 $ if $y \ne 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range of $\cos$ is $\mathbb C$. In order to prove that, take a $w\in\mathbb C$ and solve the equation $\cos z=w$. Then\begin{align}\cos z=w&\iff e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2w\\&\iff e^{2iz}-2we^{iz}+1=0\\&\iff \bigl(e^{iz}\bigr)^2-2we^{iz}+1=0.\end{align}So, solve the equation $Z^2-2wZ+1=0$ with respect to $Z$. If $Z$ is a solution, then $Z\neq0$ (because $0$ is not a solution) and now you take $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $e^{iz}=Z$.

The problem with your argument against the assertion that the range of $\cos$ is $\mathbb C$ is that $|e^{iz}|=1$ is false in general, although it is true when $z\in\mathbb R$.