# Find the range of $\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find the range of $\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ in the complex plane.

My idea is that $\frac1z$ has range $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, and $\sin(z)$ is an entire function with range $\mathbb{C}$. Then $\sin\left(\frac1z\right)$ has range $\mathbb{C}$ since $\sin\left(\frac1z\right)$ can reach $0$ at $2k\pi$, where $(k\neq 0)$ on the real line.

Comment: Your reasoning is right.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks a lot.

Comment: Technically, $\sin(1/z)$ can reach zero at $\frac{1}{2k\pi}.$ Also, you don't need the $2$ in the denominator. But otherwise, fine.

Comment: Do you already know the range of $\sin$ is all of $\mathbb C?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hi, I saw an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2429378). Probably I can also used the Little Picard Theorem.

Comment: @Flashhh Little Picard only gives you that the range is all of $\Bbb C$, perhaps minus a point. Showing that the sine function doesn't have that "minus one point" (unlike, for instance, $e^z$), is basically as difficult as not using Picard's.